# Is an ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller's Edit Action vulnerable to hacking the primary key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

This post [ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel vulnerable to hacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506087/asp-net-mvc-updatemodel-vulnerable-to-hacking) asked the same question, but none of the answers specifically addressed hacking of the primary key.

Given code like this in a Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(string accountNumber, FormCollection formValues)
    {
      ...
    }
```

What is preventing a malicious user from modifying the value of accountNumber in the POST and thereby updating a completely different record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevents this, just like nothing prevents somebody from making a request to http://example.com/users/edit/12345 (where 12345 is an account you don't have access to).  You as the application developer are responsible for verifying that the user making the current request is actually authorized to access the resource being requested.

The answer to your particular question is the same as the answer to the question you linked to.  The primary key isn't really special.  If the user shouldn't be able to modify some property of the model, use the [Bind] attribute to control what properties are allowed to be bound.  Even better - don't have disallowed properties on the model in the first place.  (If you really wanted to stick to the second pattern, you can't use ORMs for binding, but I always recommend that anyway when I do security audits of MVC codebases.)

Comment: The OP on the other post had specifically asked about the "id" and, since it wasn't addressed in the answers, I wanted to be absolutely clear.  Thanks Levi.