# ASP.NET MVC Where to put custom validation attributes

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been fiddling with some ASP.NET MVC3 solution structures and I have settled on a design that is made up of the following projects:

```
MyApp.Web -  MVC3 Web Layer
MyApp.Data - Repositories and infrastructure for managing data
MyApp.Domain - POCO Entities
MyApp.Service - Service layer through with I manipulate the model
MyApp.Test - doh
```

Where would you put your custom validation attribute classes? As far as I'm concerned they should go in the Domain project because they are specific to the entity classes that live there, but then I would need to reference a number of dlls such as System.Web.MVC and I would have liked to have kept references in that project to a bare minimum. Thoughts?

**Update:**

I removed all attributes from my Domain project and created view models to wrap them in the Web project.
Placed all my custom validation classes in a folder in the web project. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to reference the web dlls. Only `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Put the validation attributes where they are use.d

### Update

> Why not? Almost every example I've seen uses POCOs in views. What's the alternative? Creating some kind of wrapper classes for my POCOs?

Because of:

**Security**

Let's say that you got a User POCO with an `IsAdmin` field. By using the POCO, the ModelBinder in MVC will set that property if it's POSTed by a "hacker" who therefore gain admin access.

**Isolation**

Using the POCO in your view makes your View indirectly dependent of your database. Sure, POCOs are supposed to remove that dependency. But in reality they seldom do.

**Customization**

You do seldom show all values in a view as they are stored in the db.

The code to adapt a model should not be in the view, but in the viewmodel. Use as little logic as possible in your views.

Comment: you need it for client side validation ie to implement IClientValidatable

Comment: Your POCOs shouldn't be used in your views.

Comment: Why not? Almost every example I've seen uses POCOs in views. What's the alternative? Creating some kind of wrapper classes for my POCOs?

Comment: @woggles, then those are bad examples that you have seen :-)

Comment: Because of Security, Isolation and Customization. a) Let's say that you got a `User` POCO with an `IsAdmin` field. By using the POCO, the ModelBinder in MVC will set that property if it's posted by a "hacker". b) Using the POCO in your view makes your View indirectly dependent of your database. c) Your ViewModel should contain logic to adapt it, not your view (remove all code from views and add it to the viewmodels instead).

Comment: @jauffin Ah ok good example. @Darin I'll download your sample project and have a look at it again :) Thanks guys

Comment: Then again say that you have one controller/view that let's you edit the isadmin field, you would still get exposed to security issues by just copying the field from a viewmodel to a domainobject... For security issues and "over-posting" in particular I would use a whitelist of allowed values/fileds to be bound. And I would definitively start out by editing the domain objects.

Comment: @Konstantin: Incorrect. The IsAdmin field is a domain property and should never added to the view model. It can therefore never be "leaked" over to the domain model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506087/asp-net-mvc-updatemodel-vulnerable-to-hacking

Comment: Read again what I'm saying. There is no `ViewModel.IsAdmin`

Comment: Let's say you have on view where you can edit a users first name and one view where you can edit the users last name then you would actually create to view models? That sounds hard to maintain. I think it is easier and just as secure to have a user with first name and last name and then whitelist the fields the view is allowed to edit...

Comment: So I would say that the security issue is just as valid if you keep copying data from viewmodel to a domain model without whitelisting

Comment: Your example is a edge case, and I do not consider FirstName and LastName to be security problems. Hence I would not create two view models but only one ViewModel that exclude domain model properties that should never be altered. Feel free to use domain models in your views if that works for you. You *will* have problems sooner or later unless your application is very simple.

Comment: White/black listing is imho a hack, since it need to repeated on every action to work. It's duplicated code and harder to maintain. Using a specific viewmodel makes the intent much more clear. Both in your model and your controller.

Answer (score 4):

I would create these attributes on the Web Project and append them to the viewmodel instead of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I would have DataAnnotation Attributes in your Web Project, preferably in a Common.Attributes folder.  I think what jgauffin was getting at (and I'd agree) is that your CustomAttributes should really be decorating ViewModels vs Entities in your Domain project.

Answer (score 0):

I would have followed your original intent of adding the attributes to the Domain objects