# Need expert's voice for mvc beginner about Controller & Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am quite new to MVC. I am having the following questions, please help me clarify those questions, thanks a lot.

Q1. Where should I populate my view model? e.g. My view model is very big, and contains a lot of the dropdown listbox, multi select list and the other few complex objects. I am currently populate them inside the view model self, by passing the model through the constructor, and load all the object data within the constructor. I also see my college populate the viewmodel inside controller. so I am confusing now, coz lots of people suggest to keep the controller small and skinny.

Q2. We are using the linq2sql as data access layer, should I use the table entity in my viewmodel instead of creating separate model class? Expert said it's bad, but if create seperate model class, I basically repeat them and I also need to copy those value to linq 2sql entity every time when I want to persist data, it's not that fun, too much work.

Comment: As software developer, you always want to find the best approach to complete your task, it's not time saving only, but also improve yourself skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lots of people suggest to keep the controller small and skinny.

Yes. What people mean is that the controller should not contain any logic, except for model <-> view mapping. With model I mean the "**M**" in MVC.

> Q2. We are using the linq2sql as data access layer, should I use the table entity in my viewmodel instead of creating separate model class? Expert said it's bad, but if create seperate model class, I basically repeat them and I also need to copy those value to linq 2sql entity every time when I want to persist data, it's not that fun, too much work.

No. You should not. Read my answer here: [ASP.NET MVC Where to put custom validation attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283829/asp-net-mvc-where-to-put-custom-validation-attributes/6283883#6283883)

Use a mapping framework for the model -> viewmodel conversion.

**Update:**

> From what I understand, you suggest to assembly the viewmodel inside the controller (I mean call the business layer or repository to get my data) and use controller to call the business logic dealing with the data, am I right?

yes. The controller is really a glue between your business layer / repositories and your views. The views (and view models) should know nothing about them and the business layer / repositories should know nothing about the controller/view.

The controller was created for just that purpose. To create an abstraction between the user interface layer and the lower layers. Hence the only code that should exist in the controller is to make that possible (and therefore following the Single Responsibility Principle)

If you start adding that logic into your view models you start to add coupling between the lower layers and the user interface layer. Doing any changes in the lower layers will therefore also affect all your view models (instead of just the controller

Comment: Thanks for your advise jqauffin. From what I understand, you suggest to assembly the viewmodel inside the controller (I mean call the business layer or repository to get my data) and use controller to call the business logic dealing with the data, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

your viewmodel should be a poco, and should most certainly not be handling the mapping of the model.  if you don't want to map your model to your viewmodel in the controller i would suggest you look at something like [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).  it makes it easy.

once you've mapped from your model to your viewmodel, any extra properties that need to be set such as your lists should be set in the controller.

as i stated previously, definitely don't tie your viewmodel to your current orm or table structure.  you never know what might need to be refactored, and if you can handle it via an automapper mapping instead of changing your view and viewmodel then you've saved yourself a significant amount of time.

Comment: So it means I will have lot of code inside my controller to populate those values which doesn't make the controller skinny.

Comment: not necessarily.  you're controller should be pretty dumb, but you should have supporting classes that handle things, a repository for handling data retrieval, etc.  once you get everything into the right class your controller can be pretty skinny even if a lot of work is happening in the background.

Comment: How about question 2, how to handle model => table entity?

Comment: same as # 1, use automapper to map back from the viewmodel to the model.